# jquery show/hide not staying after page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please check my code and problem details below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var element = jQuery('sideBar');
// check if element is Visible
var isVisible = element.is(':visible');
if (isVisible === false) {
    jQuery(".main").removeClass("oldClass");
    jQuery(".main").addClass("newClass");
}});
```

Right now I am using this code. This code is checking that if the `sideBar` is not visible then it removing `oldClass` and add `newClass`.
This code is working good when I am trying to show hide this element.

Now I want to change a little bit I want that, when I minimize the `sideBar` can it stay minimized until I want it back even if I refesh the page or change the page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Jquery doesn't retain past page load, unless you use cookies

Comment: You should store state of sideBar in local storage and use it after page load.

Comment: Thanks for checking my question. Can you have any code sample?
I don't to how to do that. If you can please help me.

Comment: Can be written `jQuery(".main").toggleClass("oldClass");
    jQuery(".main").toggleClass("newClass");`

Comment: You would have to set a persistent state of the sideBar. JQuery is just a library used with javascript. Your best bet would be to start a session and store whether the sidebar is visible or not. Are you using PHP?

Comment: mplungjan I think he wants the class to retain its property after a page refresh as well or if he leaves and comes back

Comment: @bryangators55 yes. Do you have any sample code? It will better for me.

Comment: Are you using a server side script such as php?

Comment: You should read about sessions and creating session variables. Then you can set what ever you want in the session variables which will be persistent across the server for that client until you end the session.

Comment: Hi, Can you hear me? I understand the way.. First I have to define the session and after that I push the code in a condition if session is active then code will print. But little bit confused how to write the code. I am using joomla. can you give me any suggestion.